# 'PROJECT' is not a valid parameter. Did you mean null?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit, gerrit-trigger, jenkins-job-builder

I have setup Gerrit and Jenkins. I have configured Jenkins' [gerrit-trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) plugin so Gerrit changes are validated by Jenkins.

Now, want to automatically create Jenkins jobs, using Jenkins [jobgenerator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Generator+Plugin) plugin when a new repository is created in Gerrit.

Therefore I want to create a Gerrit hook (file `./hooks/project-created`).

I have also created a Jenkins job to generate Jenkins validation job.

But when I simulate the hook manually, with
    JENKINS_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8081/jenkins
    java -jar jenkins-cli.jar  -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa build puppet_creator -p PROJECT=foo BRANCH=bar

I get the error:
    'PROJECT' is not a valid parameter. Did you mean null?

As mentioned above, the parameter are declared in my Jenkins Job, what's wrong? I have tried both `String` and `Text` parameter types.

[image: Jenkins Job Builder configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I should have RTFM properly:

Jenkins [jobgenerator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Generator+Plugin) plugin has it's own kind of parameter: `Generator Parameter` and `Generator Choice`. One must use those instead of usual  `string`, `Choice Parameter`):

[image: Jenkins parameters types]

So, this work:
[image: Jenkins job generator for Gerrit]